# Активная вкладка меню Angular

Tags: frontend, design, angular

Как запоминать на front-end'e активную вкладку? Например [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант повешать на вкладку ng-click="selectedTab = 'signIn'"

Comment: Судя по всему вам надо сохранять данные в localStorage, а при загрузке страницы смотреть наlocalStorage и делать нужную вкладку